# Units of erc20 tokens

Tags: solidity

Hello so when i have `erc20Token.transferFrom(address(this), payable(msg.sender),500);`  does it send 500 of the erc20 tokens or the smallest units of the erc20 token??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In solidity, every unit is the smallest unit. Only when we display it, do we use the decimals to format it. So to send 500 of the token, you'll need to send 500*10^(decimals).

Comment: ok thanks so it works the same way as if i had ether right? so 1 ether= 10^18

Comment: Yup. Just like that